# Examples of torsion-free abelian groups with finite automorphism group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

$\mathbb{Z}$ is a torsion-free abelian group with finite automorphism group. Are there other examples of such groups?

Jumping from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ is not good; since $\mathbb{Q}$ has infinite automorphism group. Is there any group in-between $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ with required property?

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1300715/groups-with-finite-automorphism-groups and in particular "J. T. Hallet and K. T. Hirsch. *Torsion-free groups having finite automorphism groups I & II*"

Answer (score 4):

If $G$ is a *finitely generated* abelian group, then $G \cong \mathbb{Z}^n\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{p_1^{n_1}}\oplus\dots\mathbb{Z}_{p_k^{n_k}}$ for some (not necessarily distinct) primes $p_1, \dots, p_n$, and non-negative integers $n, n_1, \dots, n_k$. If $G$ is also torsion-free, then we have $G \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$ and therefore $\operatorname{Aut}(G) \cong GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$. Note that $GL(1, \mathbb{Z}) = \{-1, 1\}$ which is finite, but $GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ is infinite for $n \geq 2$. So the only finitely generated, torsion-free abelian group with finite automorphism group is $\mathbb{Z}$.

I'm not sure about the non-finitely generated case.

Comment: OK. This convinces that we have no more *finitely generated torsion free abelian groups*. I would think about remaining case. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese so can what you did there also be a proof that $Aut(A_{n}) \simeq GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$, where $A_{n}$ is a free abelian group of rank $n$?

Comment: @JessyunBourne: No. I used this fact, I didn't prove it.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese what **would** be the easiest way to prove that $Aut(A_{n}) \simeq GL(n, \mathbb{Z})$?

Answer (score 3):

Exercise: If $f$ is any map from the set of primes to the set of non-negative integers, then (1) the subgroup $B_f$ of $\mathbf{Q}$ generated by $1/p^{f(p)}$ when $p$ ranges over primes has automorphism group reduced to $\{\pm 1\}$.

And (2) $B_f$ and $B_g$ are isomorphic if and only if $f,g$ coincide outside a finite subset. (In particular these are uncountably many non-isomorphic groups.)