# Does $Aut(G)$ finite $\rightarrow$ $G$ is finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Does $Aut(G)$ finite $\rightarrow$ $G$ is finite?

I think this is not true, because if we look at the integers under addition, there are 2 generators, $1,-1$, and the only non-trivial automorphism permutes these generators, so $Aut(\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Also you can look at the natural homomorphism $G \to Aut(G), g \mapsto (h \mapsto ghg^{-1})$, what is its kernel ?

Comment: @reuns: The kernel is the entire group (since $\mathbb Z$ is abelian and so has no nontrivial inner automorphisms), but what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1300715/groups-with-finite-automorphism-groups?rq=1), or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592550/examples-of-torsion-free-abelian-groups-with-finite-automorphism-group?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct. $ { } { } { } $